# How to filter available contacts in my screen flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, workflow

I need help with my flow, please.

I have a Contract Object, which is linked to a Company Account Object.
A Company Account Object record typically has mutliple Contacts, some of which are tutors.
For each new contract record, I need to pick an available tutor from that company.
A tutor is available IF they are not already linked to 3 other contract records.

**Can you help me with that additional filter, please?**

*I have the following basic screen flow that does list tutors, but I don't know how to add the availability filter.*
[image: I have the following basic screen flow that does list tutors, but I don't know how to add the availability filter.]

[image]

[image]

*I know this is redundant, I've been trying to understand if there's a way for me to add that filter...*
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you need help designing a solution, and there are multiple approaches here.

One you might consider is

- custom number field on the Contact object called "number of contracts"
- a rollup (using a third party tool like DLRS) to count the number of related contracts and save them to the Contact's Number of Contracts field
- In your Flow, adjust the query criteria in the getContacts element so that Number of Contracts < 3.